# JasperReport Pie Chart Example

Tags: java, reporting, jasper-reports, ireport

I am brand new to JasperReports and am slowly fighting my way through the basics. I have a situation where I do not want to fill a pie chart with DB-driven data (through a so-called *datasource*). I want to supply all the information necessary to fill the pie chart from a Java hashmap passed into the JasperFillManager at runtime.

This would include parameters to label the slices in the pie chart, set their colors, and define their weights/values (size of the slices). So, at some point in my Java code, I would be writing *something* like:

```
HashMap<String,Object> jrParams = new HashMap<String,Object>();

jpParams.put("slice_1_label", "Red Team");
jpParams.put("slice_1_color", Color.RED);
jpParams.put("slice_1_value", 67.0);
jpParams.put("slice_2_label", "Blue Team");
jpParams.put("slice_2_color", Color.BLUE);
jpParams.put("slice_2_value", 33.0);

// ... some other code

JasperFillManager.fillReport(jasperDesign, jrParams);
```

The goal I am trying to achieve here would be to have a pie chart with 2 slices; a red "Red Team" slice taking up 67% of the pie, and a blue "Blue Team" slice takig up 33%.

**I now need help "connecting the dots" between my hashmap and the JRXML/JasperDesign.**

Can someone either show me (or just help guide me) towards what sort of `<pieChart>` JRXML I would need to write in order to have my `jrParam` hashmap fill the pie chart with runtime parameters? I have made a best-attempt below but am just struggling on making total sense of it all.

```
<pieChart>
    <chart isShowLegend="true">
        <reportElement x="10" y="10" width="300" height="300"/>
        <chartTitle>
            <titleExpression><![CDATA[My First JR Pie Chart]]></titleExpression>
        </chartTitle>
    </chart>
    <pieDataset>

        <!-- Here is where I believe I need to put my two slices; not sure how -->

    </pieDataset>
    <piePlot>
        <plot backcolor="#8BA870"/>
        <itemLabel color="#000000"/>
    </piePlot>
</pieChart>
```

Thanks in advance for any help/clarification!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

zharvey,

Since you are pretty new to JasperReport i am hoping you are using the iReport Designer tool. Design a pie chart from one of the sample templates that the iReport designer has and then try to study the generated JRXML. There is a very easy sample you can look at when going to iReport->Help->Samples->Charts

My second tip for you is to use java beans or POJOs as a datasource (simply based on the code you posted). I am looking at your sample code where you are creating a Map of String label, color and values. Wouldn't be nice and easy if you had a plain old java bean class with all these three properties as instance variable? It would be easy for your report as well, because you can create a collection of bean objects which can easily be accessed and used via the JRBeanDataSource.
I feel it will make your code a little cleaner and easier to maintain.
Regards!

Comment: Mechkov thank you for your response. Yes I am using iReports (and its Charts sample) which is where I got most of the JRXML from in my question. I would agree that in most cases I would want to fill my report data with a JRDataSource, and in this case, a JRBeanDataSource. However I am merely wondering if its possible to use a pure hashmap of parameters, and if so, what the JRXML would look like. Thanks again for you response!

Comment: Alternatively, I'd accept your answer if you could edit it to provide how to write the JRXML to work with a JRBeanArrayDataSource. Say I have a PieSlice bean that has String label, Color color, and Double value as its only 3 properties, as well as standard getters/setters for each of them. I then pass the JasperFillManager an array (with size = 2 corresponding to the 2 slices in my original question) of these PieSlices at fill time. What does the JRXML need to look like now?

Comment: @Zharvey I was going to write the whole code, but stumbled upon this great explanation...Check it out...Oh, and hopefully it gives you an idea how to do it with a Map or a List data source...Let me know if you have more questions. Regards! http://gilbertadjin.wordpress.com/2009/08/09/charting-with-jasper-reports/

Comment: Very interesting! Last thought before I finally connect the dots: So I basically create a collection of PieSlice beans and pass it to a new JRBeanArrayDataSource, and then feed that to JasperFillManager. But somewhere in the JRXML I need to map the bean properties to a field. The article you pointed me to states it does this based on the bean's properties names (capitalization is important, etc.). Thus PieSlice with property Double "value" must synch up to JRXML field $F{value}, yes? Then I assume that <pieDataset> loops through the array and uses the fields in each index of my array, yes?

Comment: You are correct. The bean properties are mapped to fields, so if you if you have a "name" property in your bean then $F{PieSlice}.name or just ${name} retrieves the value. Providing, you have the getter method in your bean. Hope this helps further.

Comment: No problem. Hope it give you an idea of how to proceed from now on. Regards!

Answer (score 0):

See whether this code helps you! I've created a bar graph using the below code which uses javabean as data source. If you want to go through my jrml I can provide that also.

```
public class App{
    String cname;
    int mark;
    public void setCname(String cname){
        this.cname = cname;
    }
    public void setMark(int mark){
        this.mark = mark;
    }
    public String getCname(){
        return cname;
    }
    public int getMark(){
        return mark;
    }
    public static ArrayList<App> getDetails() {
        ArrayList<App> clist= new ArrayList<App>();
        App c1 = new App();
        c1.setCname("English");
        c1.setMark(58);
        clist.add(c1);
        c1 = new App();
        c1.setCname("Social  Studies");
        c1.setMark(68);
        clist.add(c1);
        c1 = new App();
        c1.setCname("Culture");
        c1.setMark(78);
        clist.add(c1);
        c1 = new App();
        c1.setCname("Maths");
        c1.setMark(78);
        clist.add(c1);
        c1 = new App();
        c1.setCname("Physics");
        c1.setMark(100);
        clist.add(c1);
        return(clist);
    }

    public static void main( String[] args ) {
        JasperReport jasperReport;
        JasperPrint jasperPrint;
        Map<String, Object> param = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        try {
            String sourceFileName = ".jrxml";
            jasperReport = JasperCompileManager.compileReport(sourceFileName);
            jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jasperReport,param,new JRBeanCollectionDataSource(getDetails()));
            JasperExportManager.exportReportToPdfFile(jasperPrint, ".pdf");
        }
        catch(Exception e){
        }
        System.out.println( "Hello World!" );
    }
}
```

Comment: To be clear, this still requires building the chart using iReport/JasperStudio, but the data is then filled in programatically.